Writing css custom code to change the background dependent on product in Shopify pipeline theme
I am trying to write custom CSS code to customize the existing collection brick background in my Shopify store. I want the background image to change depending on the product being displayed.
I am unable to use liquid as I haven't purchased the pipeline theme yet so I can't copy the required code to do it that way.
I have created a meta field called 'animal' linking each product in the all-collections collection to a different name category. I have uploaded images to be linked to these and used as a background for each one.
I have been able to change the background to a single image, but cannot make it change.
I have used this code to put the background image in:
.brick__collection {
    background: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0746/8603/8283/files/WS_skin.jpg?v=1719162415);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
}

